# Stored procedure date parameter not working with cast

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure with parameters:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_SCOPRO_HLP] (                            
  @dDateFrom DATE = NULL
, @dDateTo DATE = NULL                        
)
AS
-- rest of procedure
```

My question is, why this is working:

```
EXEC sp_SCOPRO_HLP 
  @dDateFrom = '2017-01-01'
, @dDateTo = '2017-01-31'
```

but this is not working (it gaves me syntax error):

```
EXEC sp_SCOPRO_HLP 
  @dDateFrom = cast('2017-01-01' as date)
, @dDateTo = cast('2017-01-31' as date)
```

Syntax error:

[image]

Comment: You cant call functions in exec statement. Prepare arguments, then do EXEC. And better don't prefix your sp's with `sp_`.

Comment: You cannot assign values to a variable like that by calling functions in an `execute` statement. Sidenote - naming user sprocs with `sp_` is a bad idea

Comment: @Raj - perhaps you have any link to that rule?

Comment: a lot of, for example this https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/169/naming-conventions-for-sql-server-stored-procedures/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following to https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/352110/t-sql-use-scalar-functions-as-stored-procedure-parameters

You can't use functions like parameters.

All the members of SQL community would agree that acceptable form should be - less code, good readability.

So the best that you can do is:

```
DECLARE @dateFromDate = cast('2017-01-01' as date)
DECLARE @dateFromTo = cast('2017-01-31' as date)

EXEC sp_SCOPRO_HLP 
  @dDateFrom = @dateFromDate
, @dDateTo = @dateFromTo
```